# Remove special characters ( \r, \n, \t ) using Xpath/Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to remove special characters from xpath.
I used the **normalize-space()**

here is my code before :

```
info = Selector(response).xpath('//table')
for sel in info:
    item = FactureItem()
    item['montantTTC']  = sel.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[6]/text()').extract()
    yield item
```

result :

[image: result]

After using **normalize-space()**, the result gives me a one line and the **for** it does not work on this item.

Here is my code after :

```
info = Selector(response).xpath('//table')
for sel in info:
    item = FactureItem()
    item['montantTTC']  = sel.xpath('normalize-space(//tbody/tr/td[6]/text())').extract()
    yield item
```

result :

[image: result]

Comment: Try `sel.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[6]/text()').extract().strip()`

Comment: I tried to do it but he gives me this error :

** AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: `[item.strip() for item in sel.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[6]/text()').extract()]`

Comment: it works very good, thank you enormously it's been a long time since I'm looking for that

Comment: @Andersson can you write the solution in response to validate it?

Comment: What exactly you want to validate?

Comment: @Andersson your second comment

Comment: Hmm... And what do you mean by *validate `[item.strip() for item in sel.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[6]/text()').extract()]`*?